# CSS submit button weird rendering on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I noticed that if I style my buttons with CSS using radius, colors and borders, they look good but in the iphone/ipad/ipod they look terrible...shouldn't be the same rendering as in Safari Desktop??

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [css styling for input buttons on ipad / iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/css-styling-for-input-buttons-on-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 525, accepted):

Oops! I just found this myself. Just add this line on any element you need:

```
   -webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: i love you, stackoverflow, and @Francesco

Comment: Brilliant, and [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/) is a great article about it from CSS tricks. It lists all the other elements changed by WebKit and Mozilla.

Comment: Compass has a mixin for this as well http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/appearance/

Answer (score 64):

Add this code into the css file:

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

This will help.

Comment: Great! Form submit button now looks as it should on my iPad

Comment: @peterkodermac please don't forget to add parent CSS class, otherwise, this may affect every input field.

Answer (score 12):

The above answer for webkit appearance worked, but the button still looked kind pale/dull compared to the browser on other devices/desktop. I also had to set opacity to full (ranges from 0 to 1)

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
opacity: 1
```

After setting the opacity, the button looked the same on all the different devices/emulator/desktop.

Comment: Setting the opacity was necessary for me as well.

Comment: I still get strange blue background on mobile for some reason.