# Styling input buttons for iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, ios, ipad

I'm using CSS to style the input buttons on my website, but on IOS devices the styling is replaced by Mac's default buttons. Is there a way to style buttons for iOS, or a way to maybe make a hyperlink that behaves like a submit button?

Answer (score 559, accepted):

You may be looking for

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

- Safari CSS notes on [`-webkit-appearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-appearance)
- Mozilla Developer Network's [`-moz-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance)

Comment: There is still a difference in button depress/:active styling, right? It ignores your styles and applies a semitransparent grey overlay?

Comment: If you're using SCSS, use `@include experimental(appearance, none);`

Comment: The link above is now dead, unfortunately (http://thinkvitamin.com/design/styling-submit-buttons-for-mobile-safari/).

Comment: One issue with this is that for `<select>` boxes, it doesn't display the arrow when on a Desktop browser. So this is best paired with a media query I think.

Comment: What... Was it really this simple? I used a lot of `CSS` lines to style it and this line was enough to do the trick?!

Comment: Did not work for me, on IPAD1... submit button still is rounded... not respecting css rules...

Comment: @FlashThunder Have you tried adding `border-radius: 0` too?

Comment: Can I actualy spit on this behaviour of Safari and any browser following this?! Really it's a PitA to do this things.. I mean it's ok that they want to add their specific rules, but it's so annoying that you have to do the tiny extra bit of cake to every browser. It's 2016 and I still have to use vendor prefixes and solutions like that. I hate it. I have to use it on the newest Safari browser right now.. really.. pure hate! +1 for your solution.

Answer (score 39):

Please add this css code

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I recently came across this problem myself.

```
<!--Instead of using input-->
<input type="submit"/>
<!--Use button-->
<button type="submit">
<!--You can then attach your custom CSS to the button-->
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That still doesn't allow me to change the height of a button. Funny thing though, as soon as I give the button a custom width the custom height is also taken into account.

Comment: This was the fix for UIkit v3.

Answer (score 7):

Use the below css

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.flat-btn {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /*For Chrome*/
  -moz-appearance: none;/*For Mozilla*/
   appearance: none;
   border-radius: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 25px 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h2>iOS Styled Button!</h2>
<input type="submit" value="iOS Styled Button!" />

<h2>No More Style! Button!</h2>
<input class="flat-btn" type="submit" value="No More Style! Button!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today using primefaces (primeng) and angular 7.
Add the following to your style.css

```
p-button {
   -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

i am also using a bit of bootstrap which has a reboot.css, that overrides it with (thats why i had to add !important)

```
button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

-webkit-appearance: none;

Note : use bootstrap to style a button.Its common for responsive.