# CSS div buttons not working on Iphone or Ipad

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, button, media-queries

I am working on a web base app for my school with different versions of CSS for handheld, tablet and desktop. I am using media queries for this. The app is almost done and it works correctly on almost all browsers and android. The app looks awesome on Iphone/Ipad however buttons do not work making the app useless in these devices.

This is what I have:

```
//Source code

<div id="signinbutton" class="blue_button">Sign In</div>

//desktop.CSS

.blue_button {
    width: 130px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0% auto 20% auto;
    background-image:url(../../images/bluebar5.png);
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bolder;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: default;
    }
.blue_button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

//Handheld.css (this overwrites css on desktop)

.blue_button {
    width: 260px;
    font-size: 18pt;
    background-image:url(../../images/bluebar6.png);
}
```

I tried applying the style to #signinbutton without success.

Comment: When you say the buttons don't work, do you mean that nothing happens when they are touched/clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by the button "don't work"? Is that a typo in your source code are are the tags actually not correctly formed? It is really hard to tell you anything without seeing a full example, as who knows what other CSS styles could be interfering.

Comment: Try <button> instead of <div>?

Comment: Correct! nothing happens when they are clicked. Here is the link: http://as.sjsu.edu/vaishak/swpIndex.jsp

Comment: Ok, I'm trying <button> Thanks!

Comment: <button> WORKS :D !!!

Comment: for iPad / iPhone buttons where you have custom css see this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/css-styling-for-input-buttons-on-ipad-iphone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a `<button>` or `<input type="button">` tag instead of a div. While the `<div>` button functionality may work in some browsers, it can be a bit of a hack compared to the traditional button tags

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your div around `<a>` like this. It's perfectly valid with html5 now.

```
<a href="#"><div id="signinbutton" class="blue_button">Sign In</div></a>
```

You just need to adjust 
Reference:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

Answer (score -1):

Try adding to the style of the `div {cursor:pointer}`.