# <div> <a> buttons not working on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, internet-explorer, button

We have some buttons that are not responsive on iPhone and Apple touch devices.

They use the following written in VB:

```
<div class="btn-group admin" data-id="Admin">
        <a class="custom-open-close" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin</a>
        <ul class="custom-dropdown-menu">
            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("page 1", "page 1", "model")%></li>
            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("page 2", "page 2", "Model")%></li>
            <li class="divider-line"></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Firstly, I have found this is awesomefont plugin, that a colleague who left had customised. I thought that changing  to  would resolve the matter, and it did resolve for iPhones. However, it broke the dropdowns on IE.

Two questions:
1, Is this the correct way to have a drop down? I cannot find the source of any classes
2, Is there a way to check the browser and load the page either div or button?

Or is there something I have done wrong?

Comment: Why is this VBA related?

Comment: Maybe my understanding, it is written in Language = VB, changed subject to remove VBA

Comment: I have tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280596/css-div-buttons-not-working-on-iphone-or-ipad

This has resulted in IE not working.

Comment: Hi, we need to see your html markup that is generated from MVC backend. Select View>Source from desktop IE to inspect the markup.
I expect that since hyperlinks are inline the focus rect does not fill the parent <li>.... or your vML generated markup is not using a href value ...links will first use the href value for the navigation event handling.
a scripted link looks like <a href="#" onclick="doclick(event);">page 1</a>... you should also use a default target="_self" for frameless browsers like Safari iOS.

Comment: <div class="btn-group admin" data-id="Admin">
            <a class="custom-open-close" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin</a>
            <ul class="custom-dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/Section1">Option1</a></li>
                <li class="divider-line"></li>
                <li><a href="/Section2">View All</a></li>                              
            </ul>
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenOpenMenuText" name="hiddenOpenMenuText" />
        </div>


This is the source, from IE the dropdowns work on hover.

Answer (score 0):

This is only HTML, the class custom-dropdown-menu is controlling the appearance of the drop down menu. If you need to debug it on IE, hit F12 and go to developer tools. example screenshot[image]