# iPad input button styling

Tags: css, forms, ipad

I have inconsistencies in styling of a form button mainly when viewing in iPad. For some reason CSS styles for `background-color` and `padding` do not apply in iPad. I get the default looking button, with gradient and round corners, which is not what I want. I also want to avoid using an image.

CSS

```
.mailBtn {
  background: #fff;
  border:0;
  color: #000;
  font: 0.625em 'SansPro Light',sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
  padding: 11px 7px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="mailBtn">
```

Any ideas as to how can I keep styling consistent across platforms with pure CSS?

Comment: @otinanai I don't want another server request for a such a simple issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use `-webkit-appearance:none` in your `.mailBtn` class. Also, if you have rounded corners at `input` fields, you can use `-webkit-border-radius:0`.

I usually *reset* both properties in my form elements like below:

```
input, textarea, button {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /*Safari/Chrome*/
    -moz-appearance: none; /*Firefox*/
    -ms-appearance: none; /*IE*/
    -o-appearance: none; /*Opera*/
    appearance: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0; 
}
```

...so that I keep style consistency between browsers.

Comment: There is also a margin/padding on the button. Any way to resolve that?

Comment: just reset the margin and padding of the button: `button{margin:0; padding:0}`

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

- Safari CSS notes on --webkit-appearance
- Mozilla Developer Network's --moz-appearance

[Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/css-styling-for-input-buttons-on-ipad-iphone)