# iphone overriding all of my styles on an input[type="submit"]

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css, submit-button

I have isolated my `input[type="submit"]` in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WT7jJ/).

The code as well,

```
input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #FFD100;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #A58B1E;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

input[type="submit"]:active, input[type="submit"]:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #A58B1E;
    top: 2px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Everything look great except, when I checked the site on my iphone. Since my client wanted a responsive website I figured this button I made would look great on every device.

Oh boy, I was so wrong because on my iphone the button is truly hideous. I am including an image to what the mobile view looks like and the url to the site.

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can override it?

---

([Chatfield Drilling Live Site](http://chatfielddrilling.com/Chatfield%20V2/contact.html))

[image: Submit button problem]

Comment: possible duplicate of [css styling for input buttons on ipad / iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/css-styling-for-input-buttons-on-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be looking for:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: Hmm that seemed to do the trick. Should I do this for every input I have? They all seem to display my styles just fine.

Comment: I first came accross this when i was in need of a fix: http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/14/css-webkit-appearance/ - very useful to know - you can apply where you see fit

Comment: .. also forgot to answer, yes you can use it on inputs / textareas

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you so much for the article and I'm glad it was a easy fix. :]

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `-webkit-appearance:none` in your button.

Also, if you have round corners at input fields you can use the following CSS:

```
input {
    -webkit-border-radius:0; 
}
```