# Button CSS style not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, button, styles

I've created a simple form. However, the button style does not work on iOS (neither in Chrome, nor Safari). Any ideas?

```
.submit{
    width:100%;
    background:#17AADF;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:16px;
    margin-top:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.submit:hover{
    background:#000;
}

<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: I've solved it myself by adding one line of code into css:
    -webkit-appearance: none;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling input buttons for iPad and iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/styling-input-buttons-for-ipad-and-iphone)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
.submit { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

jsfiddle : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep816/MhwK4/)

Comment: To target Firefox for iOS (or any OS really) use `-moz-appearance: none`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

it will help

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above with no luck, by itself, the

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

is important but did not work.

Then I stumbled across this piece of code

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(/iP(hone|ad)/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {}, false);
    }
}
```

Once that script was included, along with using pseudo element

```
:active
```

the CSS to change buttons on touch worked.