# Radio button looks like checkbox on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, checkbox, radio-button

I am using `type='radio'` but on iPad the radio button looks like a checkbox:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mjlq.png]

Comment: try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: Reference :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/styling-input-buttons-for-ipad-and-iphone