# Why is the styling of my HTML button looking different on my iPhone?

Tags: html, ios, css

Would like to know why my HTML button looks so different on my IPhone, images below show it. 
First Image how it should look, 2nd how it looks on my iPhone.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #47ca6b;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: Adding '-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;' fixed my problem, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling input buttons for iPad and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/styling-input-buttons-for-ipad-and-iphone)