# CSS Button background overridden

Tags: css

I’m trying to simply to make a login form for this website.  When I look at the submit button on my phone, the css for the button is crudely altered. But on chrome on my laptop, it looks perfect.

View the website here:
https://jakeandiramusic.com/vipcenter/login.php

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/styling-input-buttons-for-ipad-and-iphone
"Styling input buttons for ipad and iphone"

Please use the search bar next time dude ^_^

From what Ive seen, the css is relatively the same, but look through the Documentation in the answer in that question, it should give some useful input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling input buttons for iPad and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/styling-input-buttons-for-ipad-and-iphone)

Comment: I used inspect element and your button doesn't look altered. Can you take a screenshot of what you are see'ing?

Comment: I’m sorry. I didn’t see that question. That looks like it will solve my problem.

Comment: No the source was not altered, the appearance looked different. It was a WebKit default.