# iOS input [type="search"] is not working after refresh

Tags: css, iphone, safari, webkit

The search bar that I have in my PWAs looks weird on iPhone, so I researched and managed to find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/styling-input-buttons-for-ipad-and-iphone) to it.

However, the CSS styling will only apply to the search bar when I first land or come from another page

[image: image1]

When I refresh the page, it will look like this.

[image: image2]

Here is my css styling.

```
input[type="search"] {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Does anyone know what is the exact reason?