# CSS3 button renders differently on web vs iOS

Tags: button, css

I found some code for generating CSS3 buttons which I'm using on my site. The buttons look great when viewed in the browser. However, on the mobile web version of my site (which uses the same styles) the buttons render differently. Even stranger, if I use Safari and view my site with User Agent of iPhone the buttons look as they should. However in iOS Simulator they don't. Can someone help me understand why?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
.button, #button .button, li.button .button { 
  display: inline-block; 
  zoom: 1; 
  *display: inline; 
  vertical-align: baseline; 
  outline: none; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  padding: .5em 1.5em .55em; 
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em; 
  -moz-border-radius: .5em; 
  border-radius: .5em; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
}

.orange, #button .orange { 
  color: #fef4e9; 
  border: solid 1px #da7c0c; 
  background: #f78d1d; 
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left, top, left bottom, from(#faa51a), to(#f47a20)); 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #faa51a, #f47a20); 
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#faa51a', endColorstr='#f47a20'); 
}
```

Here is how it renders in the browser:

[image]

And here is how it renders on an iPhone:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I caught my mistake. I had the wrong syntax for `-webkit-gradient`. Instead of:

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left, top, left bottom, from(#faa51a), to(#f47a20));
```

It's...

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#faa51a), to(#f47a20));
```

I had a comma between left and top where it shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 14):

Apply **"-webkit-appearance:none;"** on your css properties and add this line
**"input[type=submit], input[type=Reset]{ -webkit-appearance:none; }"**.

Answer (score 4):

As Shakti says you should just put the following css for the button.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

This is explained further in this question:

'[CSS submit button weird rendering on iPad/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438567/css-submit-button-weird-rendering-on-ipad-iphone)'

It seems that on iOS the buttons have the default iOS rounded look if you supply just a simple background color :

```
background: orange
```

But if you supply a gradient then this is effectively overriding the `appearance` css property to use a custom style.

But because you had the wrong syntax it was giving you the iOS look.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an SVG as your background image (generator can be found [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html))? Using this worked on an iPhone 3G I have lying around (jsFiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YSpdn/)):

```
background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imc5MDQiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjEwMCUiIHkyPSIxMDAlIj4KPHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI0ZBQTUxQSIgb2Zmc2V0PSIwIi8+PHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI0Y0N0EyMCIgb2Zmc2V0PSIxIi8+CjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZzkwNCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==);
```

This is compatible with IE9, Chrome, Safari and Opera. This will not work with IE7/8. What I suggest is using an IE specific stylesheet or adding to the .orange class instructions to apply the style to IE7 or IE8 and below. More info on that [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go, but is there any reason why it's not working as is?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why. I have limited iOS exposure. Perhaps `-webkit-gradient` isn't supported, but something like `linear-gradient` or `-webkit-linear-gradient` is. [This CSS gradient generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) might also interest you, though the Microsoft one using SVG is handy since one definition works on most modern browsers.

Comment: Can't edit my post, but I meant to say that `linear-gradient` may be supported and while `-webkit-linear-gradient` is.

Comment: Found my mistake - I had the wrong gradient syntax. Thanks for your help though!