# iphone giving weird css button styles and appearance none kills android styles, solutions?

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone

I know there are tons of ios display problems in stackoverflow and other places online and all of their one solution is giving

`web-kit-appearance: none`

such as the post below

[CSS submit button weird rendering on iPad/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438567/css-submit-button-weird-rendering-on-ipad-iphone)

But I happen to know that this also kills the radio buttons and checkbox in androids.  It solves the ios styling problem and another problem comes up.

Does anyone know any solutions about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the iDevice overwriting your case button styles.  You can make use of the !important tag to overwrite the rendered styles.