# Why is my button style changing when on laptop and mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, button, styles

I cant figure out why my button style would change when its on a laptop running safari compared to a phone in this case an iPhone running safari.

**HTML code :**

```
<div id="img_container">
<img src="../assets/images/hotdrinks.png" style="hight:50%;">
<button class="button" onClick="parent.location='hotdrinks.html'"> Hot Drinks Menu </button> 
</div>

<div id="img_container">
<img src="../assets/images/craftbeer.png" style="hight:50%;">
<button class="button" > Craft Club </button>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#img_container {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
}

.button {
position:absolute;
bottom:10px;
right:10px;
width:200px;
height:50px;
font-family: test;  
color: #000000;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

Laptop:
[image: Image 1 on Laptop]

Phone:
[image: Image 2 on Phone]

Comment: Since you are not changing the default look of the button, it will look different depending on the browser you are using.

Comment: To avoid this problem with future elements and browsers, use something like Normalize.css (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: I had a similar issue using bootstrap and defined a button a as follows: `<a type="button" class="btn" href=#>press link</a>`. Removing `type="button"` solved it ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari on the iphone and ipad applies some default rendering on buttons.

Try, -webkit-appearance: none;

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438567/css-submit-button-weird-rendering-on-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iPhone and iPad applies its default styling.
Use:

```
<button type="button">
```

and then add the rest. It shall work perfectly.